# PostGIS: Spatial Joins Summing using Lats/Lngs

Tags: postgis

I have a table, called `pets`, with lats and lng coordinates and variables and a table that was created by uploading a shape file, called `city`, with columns `left, right, top, bottom, lat, lng,` and  `geom.`

```
    lat    lng   cats  dogs
   -99.4   42.1   2     0
   -98.1   44.3   1     1
   -99.7   43.6   0     3 
   -99.8   42.0   2     1
```

I'm wondering how I would construct a query that will sum up the number of cats and dogs within each boundary. Usually I would do a spatial join in QGIS but my dataset is too large and it crashes before successfully joining the two.

I am pretty familiar with QGIS and Postgres, but very new to PostGIS. I've constructed a query but unsuccessful in getting the answer I needed:

```
select sum(pets.dogs)
from pets, city
WHERE ST_Within(pets.dogs, city.geom);
```

Any pointers or resources on PostGIS written for a newbie would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `pets` table needs a [GeometryColumn](http://postgis.net/docs/AddGeometryColumn.html) representing the lat/lng. Add it like this:

```
psql> SELECT AddGeometryColumn ('my_schema','pets','geom',4326,'POINT',2);
psql> UPDATE pets SET geom=ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(lng, lat), 4326);
```

For large datasets, it's advisable to add a [spatial index](http://postgis.net/docs/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html#gist_indexes) to the column:

```
psql> CREATE INDEX geom_idx ON pets USING GIST (geom);
```

This should allow for speedy queries like:

```
psql> SELECT sum(pets.dogs)
      FROM pets, city 
      WHERE ST_Within(pets.geom, city.geom);
```

This will give a single count of all dogs within any city geometry. Group by city name (or id) to get counts by city:

```
psql> SELECT city.id, city.name, sum(pets.dogs)
      FROM pets, city 
      WHERE ST_Within(pets.geom, city.geom)
      GROUP BY city.id;
```

Comment: Thanks! This makes perfect sense! I have a question, /I fixed up the `update` query to include the double precision type for the lats and longs. However when I run thes query: `UPDATE voters_map_data SET geom=ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(lng::double precision, lat::double precision), 4326)`  PostGIS returns the error `cannot recognize input for type double precision` , any thoughts?